# quitar datos en 0 de un query

Tags: sql, join, usecase

Estoy creando unas consultas usando un case y me regresa los datos que quiero pero también me llena de 0 o NULL, se que es por el ELSE.

como puedo hacer para que no me regrese los 0 o los NULL y todo quede en una sola linea

este es mi consulta

```
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 530 THEN SUM(A1.Quantity)  END AS 'Linea_Assy',
        CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 170 THEN SUM(A1.Quantity)  END AS 'Linea_Disco',
        CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 410 THEN SUM(A1.Quantity)  END AS 'Linea_Rim',
        CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 790 THEN SUM(A1.Quantity)  END AS 'Linea_ED',
        CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 1020 THEN SUM(A1.Quantity) END AS 'RRO TC',
        CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 840 THEN SUM(A1.Quantity)  END AS 'RRO ED',
        CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 1420 THEN SUM(A1.Quantity) END AS 'Linea_GP12'
    FROM Part_v_Production_e A1
    INNER JOIN Part_v_Part_Operation_e B1 ON A1.Part_Operation_Key = B1.Part_Operation_Key
    WHERE Convert(DATE,A1.Record_Date)  BETWEEN @F_INICIO AND @F_FINAL
    GROUP BY B1.Operation_No
```

y este es mi resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías añadir a la pregunta el resultado esperado?

Comment: que todo quede en una sola linea y no aparezcan los 00 de relleno

Comment: ¿probaste con `HAVING`? Fíjate en el siguiente [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp), espero que te ayude.

Comment: puedes mostrar B1.Operation_No en el select tambien?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo que usas SQL Server (te falto especificar); te comento a continuación.

Te sugiero el `CASE` colocarlo dentro del `SUM` y colocar en el `WHERE` la/las condición(ones) mediante las cuales quieres se incluya/excluyan resultados. Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 530 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Linea_Assy',
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 170 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Linea_Disco',
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 410 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END)  AS 'Linea_Rim',
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 790 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END)  AS 'Linea_ED',
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 1020 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'RRO TC',
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 840 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END)  AS 'RRO ED',
    SUM(CASE WHEN B1.Operation_No = 1420 THEN A1.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Linea_GP12'
FROM Part_v_Production_e A1
INNER JOIN Part_v_Part_Operation_e B1 ON A1.Part_Operation_Key = B1.Part_Operation_Key
WHERE Convert(DATE,A1.Record_Date)  BETWEEN @F_INICIO AND @F_FINAL
    AND ISNULL(A1.Quantity,0)>0 /* Aquí quitamos todo los que sea 0 y los NULL; realmente todo lo NULL y menor igual a 0 (cero)*/
/* GROUP BY B1.Operation_No // Se omite gracias gbianchi */
```

Lo único no muy claro es eso de "en una sola línea". Prueba quitando el `GROUP BY` a tu sentencia original.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**
En la sección del `WHERE`

Con lo siguiente se omite cualquier valor `NULL` y que sea menor o igual a 0:

```
    AND ISNULL(A1.Quantity,0)>0 /* Aquí quitamos todo los que sea 0 y los NULL; realmente todo lo NULL y menor igual a 0 (cero)*/
```

Para excluir los 0 y `NULL` (unicamente esos 2) debe ser:

```
    AND ISNULL(A1.Quantity,0)<>0 /* Debe ser distinto de cero; así con ello se incluye valores negativos y positivos */
```

Comment: Si esta el group by, va a seguir generando multiples filas... mmmm.. es raro...

Comment: Cierto @gbianchi , se me paso omitirlo *(por usar copia-pegar :D ).

Comment: lo que no entiendo es como acepto tu respuesta (que sin el group by es claramente mejor que la mia) si en realidad, no funciona...

Comment: y otra cosa, tu isnull(a1.quatitity) no aporta nada, porque si es 0, va a sumar 0 y si es null no va a sumar nada... o sea, no esta quitando registros que no importen...

Answer (score 2):

Lo que vos queres, se puede lograr pero es mucho mas complicado de escribir que lo que pensas.

El tema es que la base de datos te muestra 8 registros no por el else, si no porque vos estas agrupando por Operation_No, y seguro hay 8 tipos de datos en ese campo.

Vos queres mostrar todo en una sola fila, y no se porque, pero se puede solucionar haciendo un query que incluya las 7 filas que vos queres, pero todas por separado.

O sea, tenes que hacer algo asi:

```
Select 
    (Select sum(A1.Quantity) 
    FROM Part_v_Production_e A1
    INNER JOIN Part_v_Part_Operation_e B1 ON A1.Part_Operation_Key = B1.Part_Operation_Key
    WHERE Convert(DATE,A1.Record_Date)  BETWEEN @F_INICIO AND @F_FINAL and B1.Operation_No = 530) 'Linea_Assy',
    (Select sum(A1.Quantity) 
    FROM Part_v_Production_e A1
    INNER JOIN Part_v_Part_Operation_e B1 ON A1.Part_Operation_Key = B1.Part_Operation_Key
    WHERE Convert(DATE,A1.Record_Date)  BETWEEN @F_INICIO AND @F_FINAL and B1.Operation_No = 170) 'Linea_Disco',
    etc etc
from dual
```

Lo que si.. dependiendo de tu db, esto puede llegar a ser muy lento...